# tensorflow.contrib

Tags: python, tensorflow

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'
I've had this error on two AI related projects so far and I can only see this occurring more and more often. The two projects for reference are GPT-2 (GPT-3 is not available to the public) and real-time-voice-cloning

What I've read on the internet so far, is that tensorflow.contrib was meant to be deleted with the new version of tensorflow 2.0. However, these projects don't support tensorflow 2.0, they were made for tensorflow 1.5

So my question is does anyone know of an archive for tensorflow.contrib so I can use these very popular irreplaceable projects?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it and this is how:

Install anaconda
If your terminal now begins with (base):
conda deactivate
Don't have anaconda load your base environment on startup (caused issues for me)
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
conda create –name project_name
conda activate project_name
conda install pip python==3.7
conda install tensorflow-gpu==1.15 or conda install tensorflow==1.15 if using cpu

(Installing tensorflow 1.15 had tensorflow.contrib in it already I think...)
Best of luck if you're having this issue too.